ideals generated by symmetric elements
Would you help to solve Exercise 5 of Chapter 1 in the book of involutions: "Show that in a central simple algebra with involution, every left or right ideal is generated by a symmetric element, unless the algebra is split and the involution is symplectic."
Every finite-dimensional simple algebra $A$ has a minimal left or right ideal $V$ and $A \cong \text{End}_D(V)$ where $D=\text{End}_A(V)$. If $A$ is central, then so is $D$. Any involution corresponds to a nonsingular hermitian or skew-hermitian form $$h: V \times V \to D.$$
The involution is symplectic if the form is skew-hermitian.
Now, how can I proceed?
